Do all gods lie inside of Shri Krishna / Vishnu?
Krishna showed his Vishwa Roop to Arjun.
I want to know if all gods lie inside of Shri Krishna /Shri Hari Vishnu .
Does this include big gods like - Shiva, Brahma, Tri Devis ?
Is it written somewhere else, in some Puranas, that that all gods lie inside Shri Hari Vishnu ?

Related1 Related 2

All universe exist within Krishna -

She (Yaśodā) beheld therein the universe consisting of mobiles and
immobiles, the ethereal dome, the cardinal points, the sphere of the
earth along with the mountains, continents and oceans, the wind, the
fire (of lightning), the moon, the stars, the (whole of the) planetary
system, (elements like) water, fire, wind and the sky, (the presiding
deities of) the senses and the mind, subtle elements and the three
guṇas.


Chapter 8, 10th Skandha, Srimad Bhagavatam.


The question of lying inside or outside is itself fallacious. Is Krishna/Vishnu a container that things will live inside him?
Are all Gods manifestations of Krishna/Vishnu? The answer is a qualified yes which depends on your understanding.
Is Krishna/Vishnu one of the Saguna forms, completely Ishvara, non different from Parabrahman? If that is your understanding, then everything is contained in Ishvara, the answer is affirmative. The same goes with Shiva or Shakti, they are equally Ishvara.
Vishwaroop is simply Krishna showing the swarup of Parabrahman when it appears with forms, to Arjuna. He is non-different with Parabrahman as himself Isvara, hence he is able to show it to whoever he wishes, be it Yashoda(Bhagwatam) or Arjuna(Gita).

ShriKrishna revealed it to Arjun, after 11 chapters, through divya-chakshu.
This is very deep and experiential. Theory will confuse most people.
There is an order and chain of adhikari's. Some of the one's you mention are from eternal abode "param dhama".
You may have to go through Gopinath Kaviraj ji's texts to understand this aspect.
His books are listed on
https://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A5_%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%9C
I haven't read any other yogi explaining it so clearly.
